# replace word with a variable in line start with

Tags: sed, awk, printf

I need to know how to replace this line in fstab:

```
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
```

with:

```
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults,size=4G        0 0
```

I tried:

```
MEM_SZ=4
sed '/^tmpfs/ s/defaults.*$/defaults,size=${MEM_SZ}G/' /etc/fstab
```

but output was without 0 0 and the size value didn't changed with the variable :

```
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults,size=${MEM_SZ}G
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified the sed and replace single quotes with double and added \t to insert tab

```
sed "/^tmpfs/ s/defaults.*$/defaults,size=${MEM_SZ}G\t 0 0/" /etc/fstab
```